# How to define what character is generated using KeyRoutedEventArgs?

Tags: c#, regex, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to validate the information entered in a text box - I am going to allow only `Cyrillic` characters. To do that, I am using the following regular expression:

> @"[\u0400-\u04FF]{1}"

and binding a function to the `KeyDown` event of the text box. Note, that the expressions is working perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
private void txtBoxName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Key.ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), @"[\u0400-\u04FF]{1}"));

    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back || Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), @"[\u0400-\u04FF]{1}"))
    {
        //return true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The issue is I am not able to correctly identify what is the real character generated. For  example:

[image]

Gives me(this is the code generated by the debug statements) and not `Я`:

```
Shift 'MST_61462004_E1T04.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 
'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled. 
False 
S 
False
```

And I believe this is why the validation is not working.

Comment: Did you try [OriginalKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.originalkey.aspx) instead of `Key`?

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.key.aspx) KeyRoutedEventArgs.Key does not necessarily represent mapped Unicode character of the pressed key:

> Depending on the input device, this can be a mapped value. For raw,
>   unmapped event data, see the OriginalKey property.

In your case (Keyboard Device), it just represents [virtual keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx) and there is a mapping process that TextBox does internally to convert the virtual key to zero or more unicode characters. In Win32, it could be done by [MapVirtualKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function but there is nothing similar to it in WinRT.

You have a few choices:

- Validating on [TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.textchanged.ASPx) event of the TextBox instead (I prefer this one)
- Using a very simple mapping tightly coupled to the expected keyboard layout as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22238676/3956290)
- Implementing a full version of MapVirtualKey (It takes lots of effort)

Answer (score 0):

The `Key` property of the [`KeyRoutedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.key.aspx) returns the *mapped* event value. Use [`KeyRoutedEventArgs.OriginalKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.originalkey.aspx) to get unmapped value.

> Depending on the input device, the input button might be mapped to a different key value.

Also, you do not have to use the `{1}` quantifier, it is redundant, as the character class `[\u0400-\u04FF]` is capturing  exactly 1 character. Or, to shorten it, you can use a Unicode category class `\p{IsCyrillic}`.

So, use

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back ||
    Regex.IsMatch(e.OriginalKey.ToString(), @"[\u0400-\u04FF]"))
{
    //return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no `OriginalKey`, only `OriginalSource`.

Comment: Then, you need to use `TextChanged` event. It is highly possible the problem is with `KeyDown` that usually works with "virtual" keys.

Comment: I have a task to solve (it is specified that the values need to be validated on `KeyDown` event) - I have validation on button click event, that is working fine. I guess, there is no way to implement similar on `key` event, yet.

Comment: It is curious: do you have `RoutedEventArgs` instead of `KeyRoutedEventArgs`?

Comment: I have `KeyRoutedEventArgs`. I am using `windows runtime` and `8.1 windows phone`